# Is it possible to log the usb mount information in linux?

Tags: usb, logging

I use Arch linux and I need to know if someone mounts a usb device in my absence. I don't want to lock the system as an alternative.

Does linux make a log on itself or I have to add some script or utility to do so?

Comment: [method by which I can track down a list of flash drives](//superuser.com/q/1041548)

Comment: [Does Xubuntu keep a log of all USB devices ever connected to the system?](//superuser.com/q/645459)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89227/how-can-dmesg-content-be-logged-into-a-file

Comment: Not interested in preventing anything (such as mounting), just want to see what was plugged in after the fact?

Answer (score 0):

When someone attaches a USB device it is being logged in dmesg, just fire that command in the terminal.
You can write script to grep your dmesg file when it is modified using inotify tools.